# Constructor is not callable with RealmProvider in React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, realm

I have been trying to do the basic `Realm` implementation in my React Native app. I have StackNavigator and i am trying to wrap that with `RealmProvider`. But it shows the error saying `constructor is not callable`. Here's the code:

```js
import { createRealmContext } from '@realm/react';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const appId = "";
const realmConfig = { id: appId, timeout: 10000 }
const TodoSchema = {
  name: 'Todo',
  primaryKey: '_id',
  properties: {
    _id: 'objectId',
    text: 'string'
  }
}


const Navigation = () => {
  const scheme = useColorScheme();
  const isDarkMode = scheme === "dark";
  const logStatus = true;
  const config = {
    schema: [TodoSchema],
  };
  const { RealmProvider } = createRealmContext(config);

 
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
      onReady={() => {
        isReadyRef.current = true;
      }}
      theme={isDarkMode ? DarkTheme : LightTheme}
    >
      <RealmProvider>  // This is throwing the error
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name={SCREENS.INSTALLMANUAL}>
              {(props) => <InstallManual {...props} />}
            </Stack.Screen>
            <Stack.Screen name={SCREENS.FORGET_PASSWORD}>
              {(props) => <ForgetPasswordScreen {...props} />}
            </Stack.Screen>
          </>
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name={SCREENS.HOME} component={HomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name={SCREENS.DETAIL}>
              {(props) => <DetailScreen {...props} />}
            </Stack.Screen>

            <Stack.Screen name={SCREENS.SLIDESHOW}>
              {(props) => <SlideshowScreen {...props} />}
            </Stack.Screen>
          </>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </RealmProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

I have created context but when i try to wrap it with RealmProvider, it shows the error. What should be done here?

Answer (score -2):

I personally have experienced this annoying issue

```
constructor is not callable
```

but not in scope of Realm, but when trying to establish websocket connection from the default react-native application.
And in my particular case point was in importing/exporting and, possibly, in mixture of .js and .tsx JS files.

When I have put all the code in one file (App.tsx) the error has gone.